# Does mean deviation from mean depend on change of origin and scale?

Tags: descriptive-statistics

I know that SD depends on change of scale and not on change of origin. what about mean deviation?
Mean deviation from mean = $\frac{\sum|X_{i}- \overline X|}{N}$.

Comment: How do you define `mean deviation`?

Comment: that is mean absolute deviation to be precise.

Comment: The mean deviation from the mean is always zero, so that counts as invariant to changes of origin, scale and regime in power. What you mean is widely understood, but as @gunes implies, mentioning _absolute_ at least when you introduce the term is a good idea,

Comment: A better index is Gini's mean difference: the mean absolute difference between all possible pairs of observations.  It doesn't rely on the mean as the centering index.

Comment: The term "mean deviation" has a long history in statistics and (particularly in older works) is nearly always intended to mean "mean absolute deviation from the mean"..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Distance from mean of each observation is clearly invariant to "changes of origin". 5 is as far from 3 as 1005 is from 1003, or, in a more general form: $|(a+c)-(b+c)| = |a-b|$

The scale is different, though. As $|rx-ry| = r|x-y|$, scaling your variable by a factor of $r$ will also scale your "mean deviation from mean" by a factor of $r$.